# How to add two wavess with different frequencies and amplitudes?

Tags: waves

How do I add waves modeled by the equations $y_1=A\sin (w_1t-k_1x)$ and $y_2=B\sin (w_2t-k_2x)$
How to calculate the frequency of the resultant wave?

Comment: $Y = A\sin (W_1t-K_1x) + B\sin (W_2t-K_2x)$ ; or is it something else your asking?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about the subscript.

Comment: A composite sum of waves of different frequencies has no "frequency", it is just *that* sum. Not everything has *a* frequency , for example, a square pulse has no frequency.

Comment: the way you add them is just this sum=Asin(w_1 t-k_1x)+Bsin(w_2 t-k_2x), that is all and nothing else.